# Creating a setup project with full control for users in C# winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to create an installer of C# winform application in which all user can run and edit the  the connection string in app.config file.

Comment: So, what is the question here?

Comment: Grant admin permissions to the installing user

Comment: I created the installer but need to run as administrator to change the connection string. how i can give a user(installing)permission to change connection string

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom action for your setup.

1/ Add a class, deriving from System.Configuration.Install.Installer.

2/ override OnBeforeInstall --> implement to allow user to construct a connectionstring

3/ override OnAfterInstall --> implement change of app.config

4/ Add the custom action to your setup project.